# Entity Framework inherited property as 'contained query'

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have this table:

```
[Table(Name = "Faxes")]
public class FaxRecord
{
     [Column(Name = "CompletedDate")]
     string CompletedDate { get; set; }

     // other columns...
}
```

Is it possible to add a new property `IsFinished` to `FaxRecord` **such that**:

1. `IsFinished` = `CompletedDate==null`
2. `IsFinished` may be used to query the "Faxes" sql table. (i.e. it may be used as an expression, for example calling `DataContext.GetTable<FaxRecord>().Where(fax => fax.IsFinished).ToList()` would return all the records where CompletedDate == null.

The relevant use case of this is that perhaps I would like FaxRecord to inherit from some interface for maintaining faxes, which has a property `IsFinished` rather than `CompletedDate`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is:

```
[Column(Name = "IsFinished")]
public bool IsFinished => string.IsNullOrEmpty(CompletedDate);
```

Comment: fascinating!  I don't have a column in my table named IsFinished.  but this still works?

Comment: Yes it should work. just change the Column annotation to [NotMapped] if you do not want it to be mapped to your database

Comment: Can this same principle work across `[Association]`-attributed properties? I'm getting a NotSupportedException: "The member 'ConcreteFax.IsFinished' has no supported translation to SQL."

Comment: It will work if you add the `IsFinished` column to your database. You can only create associations of columns that are part of the schema

Comment: This does not work because I cannot query a GetTable with the property IsFinished. `SqlException: Invalid column name 'IsFinished'.
Invalid column name 'IsFinished'.`

Comment: Because you don't have it in your database. You can either create that column in your database or use the lambda `fax => string.IsNullOrEmpty(fax.CompletedDate)` to filter finished `FaxRecords` in your db. There is no way to filter a table by a column that doesn't exists there.

Comment: Thanks for your hepl.